# Metabox Wordpress plugin Thickbox jQuery error- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using Metabox Plugin in Wordpress that comes with thickbox option in it.

All works fine, except for when trying to create/edit a gallery with the multiple image upload.

When I click on the 'insert gallery' button, nothing happens and I notice in the chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

The file contents are as follows

```
jQuery( function ( $ )
{
    'use strict';

    $( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.rwmb-thickbox-upload', function ()
    {
        var $this = $( this ),
            $holder = $this.siblings( '.rwmb-images' ),
            post_id = $( '#post_ID' ).val(),
            field_id = $this.data( 'field_id' ),
            backup = window.send_to_editor;

        window.send_to_editor = function ( html )
        {
            var $img = $( '<div />' ).append( html ).find( 'img' ),
                url = $img.attr( 'src' ),
                img_class = $img.attr( 'class' ),
                id = parseInt( img_class.replace( /\D/g, '' ), 10 );

            html = '<li id="item_' + id + '">';
            html += '<img src="' + url + '">';
            html += '<div class="rwmb-image-bar">';
            html += '<a class="rwmb-delete-file" href="#" data-attachment_id="' + id + '">×</a>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<input type="hidden" name="' + field_id + '[]" value="' + id + '">';
            html += '</li>';

            $holder.append( $( html ) ).removeClass( 'hidden' );

            tb_remove();
            window.send_to_editor = backup;
        };
        tb_show( '', 'media-upload.php?post_id=' + post_id + '&TB_iframe=true' );

        return false;
    } );
} );
```

and here is the line which gives the error

```
id = parseInt( img_class.replace( /\D/g, '' ), 10 );
```

Comment: Hi, Have you found a solution to this issue yet? seems like no one is looking this way. Will appreciate if you could share the way forward on this issue, thanks.

Comment: @user3619389 - I too am getting the same error now, cant seem to find the main issue thus far.

Comment: I also couldnt find the issue and i used some other way to overcome this not metabox,  ...

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the html doesn`t have img tag...
Change your code to :

```
var $img = $( '<div />' ).append( html ).find( 'i' );
url = $img.attr( 'src' ),
img_class = $img.attr( 'class' ),
id = parseInt( img_class.replace( /\D/g, '' ), 10 );
```